# A trail card says I pass if I roll an even number and die if I roll a 1. What happens if I roll a 3 or 5?

Tags: the-oregon-trail-card-game

In *The Oregon Trail Card Game*, there is a trail card that says the following:

> Roll an even number and ford the river. Roll a one and die by drowning.

What happens if I roll a 3 or a 5? Other cards have you lose a supply card on a failed roll, so I'm not sure if that happens here. But since it doesn't say, I'm wondering if there is any consequence.

<sub>This question was raised in [a review of the game](http://arstechnica.com/the-multiverse/2016/09/oregon-trail-card-game-simple-repetitive-and-youll-die-of-dysentery-a-lot/) at Ars Technica.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Board Game Geek user sent in some rules questions to Pressman Toys and received responses from the company president and game designer. They were kind enough to [post them on Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1618748/official-rule-clarification-pressman-toys), and this question was one of them:

> 1) River card: “Roll an Even number to ford the river. Roll a 1 and die by drowning.” What happens then when the person rolls a 1 and dies? Would you take that to mean the river was forded, but lost that player to drowning? What happens if a 3 or 5 is rolled?
>
> -When players are trying to ford a river and they don’t drown or ford the river play passes to the next player, who rolls to try to ford the river. This continues until all players drown or a player fords the river. No player may play another Trail Card until the river has been forded.

In other words, a result of 3 or 5 means that the river is not forded, but there are no other ill effects. The next player then attempts to ford the river. Only when a person rolls a 2, 4, or 6 is the River considered to be forded and a new trail tile may be drawn.